# Configurar el emulador android con proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask

Buenas compañeros estoy tratando de emular unos servicios en el emulador  de android studio pero la red en la que estoy conectado contiene proxy y me gustaría saber como configurar... Tengo android studio 2.1.2

ya probé colocándole en el emulador: `Settings/More/celular networks/access point name/APNs...`

```
Proxy: proxy2.sena.edu.co
puerto:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Al configurar tu APN ademas del Proxy el puerto son importantes las credenciales, usuario y password.

Para probar que funcione correctamente abre una página en el navegador del simulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en proxy va el proxy e la red o la ip del pc ??

Comment: Es el nombre del servidor proxy o su IP, en mi caso usaba el nombre pero hace meses no podía conectarme y cambie a la ip del servidor proxy.

Comment: es que utilizo esta proxy ya q es donde estudio proxy2.sena.edu.co puerto 80 osea q esto  irian en los campos y que va en contraseña y usuario q le ingreso hay ??

Comment: No, usuario y contraseña es en diferente, no necesitas usuario y contraseña para acceder a tu pc por ejemplo?

Comment: si, pues tiene dos roles uso el admin y contraseña es una predefinida osea que esos tiene que ir en el móvil ejemplo quedaría así:  proxy: proxy2.sena.edu.co, puerto: 80, usuario: ADMIN, clave: 12345  ??

Comment: Sería la contraseña que te permite acceso a internet, regularmente es la de la misma PC si estas en una red.

Comment: pues la verdad la red en la que estoy tiene una contraseña diferente ala de mi lapton

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48669/discussion-between-elenasys-and-gomez-munoz-brayan).